# Powering condenser mic while getting the signal

Tags: power, signal, sound

http://www.afrotechmods.com/groovy/amplifier_tutorial/amplifier_tutorial.htm

Look at the extreme left part of the circuit above seem to power the mic by 9v through a 5k Ohm resistor that powers the mic through same pin that spits the signal wont it cause distortion in the signal[image]

Comment: Please add the schematic (with reference link) into your question so that we don't have to follow the link to understand your question and so that the question still makes sense if the link dies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That resistor and the microphone form a voltage divider.  This means that the output voltage of these two devices will not be centered around 0V (it will have a DC offset somewhere between 0V and 9V).  The 0.1uF capacitor is a DC blocking capacitor, and the voltage at the output of that capacitor will be centered around 0V (ground) because of the output is biased by the 100k resistor.

If you build the circuit and examine the signals with an oscilloscope all of this will become obvious.

You could also simulate this using LTSpice or other simulation program.  If you want to simulate this, replace the microphone and resistor with a voltage/signal source with a DC offset of 2V generating a sine wave with an amplitude of 10mV or so (op-amp has a gain of 100, you should get about 1V out).

Comment: Thanks man helped a lot to better understand the circuit

Comment: The external resistor and the voltage source are crucial to setting the loadline for the preamplifier.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, there is almost certainly a built in FET preamp in the capsule. The resistor simply powers the internal preamp.

The electret capsule itself generally has extremely high impedance has to interface to a preamp with input impedance in the gigohms. That's why the preamp is almost always built in.

See [Rod Elliot](https://sound-au.com/articles/mic-electret.htm) for more info.